# Исключить поля при десериализации JSON

Tags: android, gson

Исходя из практического опыта, какой лучший способ для десериализации полей?

От сервера получаю огромный JSON array из 15 объектов.
Мне надо вытащить из 3 объектов половину данных.

Как это лучше сделать?

Мой план:

1. пометить ненужные поля @Expose
2. создать Pojo класс с нужными полями
3. когда будет разбирать JSON, придерживаться следующей стратегии:

   ```
      JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends");
      JSONObject contacts = friends.getJSONObject("сontacts");
      String phone = contacts.getString("mobile");
      String email = contacts.getString("email");
      String skype = contacts.getString("skype");
   ```

Обновление вопроса.
На [запрос](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/) прилетает огромный JSON.
Сайт [тут](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) ругается. Говорит, превышен максмимальный ввод символов. Мне из этого JSON необходимо вытащить пятую часть данных.

ИТОГО:

Есть JSON, но не знаю как его десериализовать в Pojo.
Не совсем понимаю, как использовать полученный объект для установки значений в UI.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. пометить ненужные поля @Expose

`@Expose` работает только в паре с методом `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`, который исключает из обработки все поля, **не** имеющие аннотации `Expose`. Чтобы исключить одно поле, нам нужно добавить аннотации **ко всем остальным полям**.

> 2. создать Pojo класс с нужными полями.

Должно сработать

---

Чтобы исключить поля из десериализации можно написать свою аннотацию:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class Exclude
```

ExclusionStrategy:

```
class AnnotationExclusionStrategy : ExclusionStrategy {
    override fun shouldSkipField(field: FieldAttributes) = field.getAnnotation(Exclude::class.java) != null
    override fun shouldSkipClass(clazz: Class<*>) = false
}
```

И применить эту стратегию

```
 GsonBuilder()
    .setExclusionStrategies(AnnotationExclusionStrategy())
    .create()
```

После чего, помеченное этой анноташкой, поле перестанет десериализироваться.

**PS** код на `Kotlin`

Comment: `transient`, не? в котлине же тоже есть...